# How to share functionality in Rust?

Tags: rust

```
struct Vector {
    data: [f32; 2]
}

impl Vector {
   //many methods
}
```

Now I want to create a `Normal` which will almost behave exactly like a `Vector` but I need to differentiate the type. Because for example transforming a normal is different than transforming a vector. You need to transform it with the tranposed(inverse) matrix for example.

Now I could do it like this:

```
struct Normal {
    v: Vector
}
```

And then reimplement all the functionality

```
impl Normal {
    fn dot(self, other: Normal) -> f32 {
        Vector::dot(self.v, other.v)
    }
    ....
}
```

I think I could also do it with [`PhantomData`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/marker/struct.PhantomData.html)

```
struct VectorType;
struct NormalType;
struct PointType;
struct Vector<T = VectorType> {
    data: [f32; 2],
    _type: PhantomData<T>,
}
type Normal = Vector<NormalType>;
```

But then I also need a way to implement functionality for specific types.

It should be easy to implement for example `add` for everything so that it is possible to add `point + vector`.

Or functionality specific to some type

```
impl Vector<NormalType> {..} // Normal specific stuff
```

Not sure how I would implement functionality for a subrange. For example maybe the dot product only makes sense for normals and vectors but not points.

Is it possible to express boolean expression for trait bounds?

```
trait NormalTrait;
trait VectorTrait;
impl NormalTrait for NormalType {}
impl VectorTrait for VectorType {}

impl<T: PointTrait or VectorTrait> for Vector<T> {
    fn dot(self, other: Vector<T>) -> f32 {..} 
}
```

What are my alternatives?

Answer (score 3):

Your question is pretty broad and touches many topics. But your `PhantomData` idea could be a good solution. You can write different `impl` blocks for different generic types. I added a few things to your code:

```
struct VectorType;
struct NormalType;
struct PointType;
struct Vector<T = VectorType> {
    data: [f32; 2],
    _type: PhantomData<T>,
}
type Normal = Vector<NormalType>;
type Point = Vector<PointType>;

// --- above this line is old code --------------------

trait Pointy {}
impl Pointy for VectorType {}
impl Pointy for PointType {}

// implement for all vector types
impl<T> Vector<T> {
    fn new() -> Self {
        Vector {
            data: [0.0, 0.0],
            _type: PhantomData,
        }
    }
}

// impl for 'pointy' vector types
impl<T: Pointy> Vector<T> {
    fn add<R>(&mut self, other: Vector<R>) {}
    fn transform(&mut self) { /* standard matrix multiplication */ }
}

// impl for normals
impl Vector<NormalType> {
    fn transform(&mut self) { /* tranposed inversed matrix stuff */ }
}

fn main() {
    let mut n = Normal::new();
    let mut p = Point::new();
    n.transform();
    p.transform();

    // n.add(Normal::new());  // ERROR:
    // no method named `add` found for type `Vector<NormalType>` in the current scope
    p.add(Point::new());
}
```

> Is it possible to express boolean expression for trait bounds?

No (not yet). But you can solve it in this case as shown above: you create a new trait (`Pointy`) and implement it for the types in your "or"-condition. Then you bound with that trait.

Comment: There's no need for `PhantomData<T>`. Just replace it with `T`.

Comment: (I think). Something like how byteorder does it.

Comment: Is there an RFC for boolean expressions in trait bounds?

Comment: @MaikKlein not exactly about the case in question, but with [this RFC](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/pull/1657) my answer would change a lot anyway.

Comment: @Shepmaster Without using `PhantomData` we have to construct an object of type `T` which is a bit problematic... so we had to bound `T: Default` or anything. I think :P